# Custom rule for new line after/before MARK in SwiftLint

Tags: swiftlint

Could you help me?
I want to write custom rule for SwiftLint.
I would like to enforce putting one blank line before and after PRAGMA MARK: //

**Example:**

*Error case*

some code\n

// MARK - Smt\n

some code\n

---

*Right case*

some code\n\n
// MARK - Smt\n\n

some code\n\n

---

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try setting the regex to match "// MARK -" with newlines preceding it and coming after it.

To make sure SwiftLint only applies this to comments, you can set "match_kinds" to just comments on the SwiftLint yml file.